# Do route parameter names have to match action method parameter names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have a web API whose routing is very generic (see below):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("3", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}/{arg2}/{arg3}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("2", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}/{arg2}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("1", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("0", "{controller}/{action}");
```

It is my understanding that in order for action methods to be matched by this routing, the action method parameters **must** be named `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`. For example, I would expect the following action methods to match:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Foo(int arg1)
{ ... }

public HttpResponseMessage Bar(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{ ... }
```

I would expect the following action method to not match:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Foo(int someOtherParameterName)
{ ... }
```

However, the project also contains action methods with parameter names that aren't `arg1`, `arg2` etc. In some environments (for example, integration tests run on our CI server), the endpoints work fine, i.e. these action methods **are** being matched. But on my development machine these endpoints do not work.

So is there some obscure config that might affect the relationship between route parameter names and action method parameter names? Or possibly a breaking change in one of the relevant dlls?

Comment: When you say the action methods are being matched: Are the parameters getting bound to any values?

Comment: They must be, because the API is live and is working. But I absolutely cannot understand how. My present understanding is that the routing system won't even select the action if the route data dictionary doesn't have values corresponding to the action method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not necessary for Route parameters to match action method parameters. Its just number of parameters that should match..